# How to show specific color on top when multiple background colors are combined in nattable?

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable, nebula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJza6.png)

I added nattable configLabel to add background color.

But what if you want to display the blue color at the top when multiple background colors are combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are managed in a `LabelStack`. The labels are interpreted top-down. That means if multiple labels are applied that all would have effect on the background color, the top most label wins. So if the blue color should win, the label that is responsible for the blue color needs to be on top of the label stack.